# Internship resume

Tags: resume, internship

I am applying for programming internships. Is it preferable to list the University you will be transferring to from a community college?

Example:

Education:

```
  Community College
  START 2014 - FINISHED 2016
  COMPUTER SCIENCE
  GPA

  University Name
  START 2016 - FINISHED 2018
  COMPUTER SCIENCE
  GPA
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about expectations at a workplace rather than in academia. You might try the [Workplace.SE].SE

Comment: @BillBarth Okay, thank you for the suggestion. I was pondering on where to post this in (academia, The Workplace, or Stackoverflow ). I usually spend my time in Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Workplace.SE.

Comment: Don't write "START" and "FINISHED". Just write the date range and the degree obtained ("Associates", "Bachelor of Science", etc.). If you're still in the program, write "Present", e.g. "2012 - Present"

Comment: @Brandin "START" & "FINISHED" were just place holders for the months. Though I thank you for the "PRESENT" advice. Did not think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only list colleges that will result in some sort of degree (AA/AS/BA/BS) or certification. List the college, list the degree, and list usually the month and year it was awarded or, like above, use the word 'expected' with a month and year to indicate a future degree.

Do not list the year you started at the university unless you are trying to explain an employment gap. If you are fresh out of high school, that information is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've advised several students on submitting applications to internships before, including students who are in the process of transferring. If you have already been admitted to this University then you should list it as the institution you are attending. Usually you put your most recent academic institution at the top. You are also free to not list the community college unless you want to (e.g. to demonstrate that you have received your AA).

For example:

Current University
BA Political Science,                            *Expected May, 2016*

Community College 
AA                                                June, 2015

Comment: @caceves Okay thank you. I am actually doubling up, I am completing my AAS Degree in Computer Science (so i can manage for a part-time at least while I finish my bachelors) and General Ed. AA off by two terms. Also I have been admitted to the University. Would these two degrees add value to my resume on top of the University?